# iOS NativeScript permission Error spawn EACCES

Tags: ios, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm trying to set up nativescript development environment.  I followed the steps as described in the official doucmentation. [Link](https://docs.nativescript.org/start/quick-setup)

After that I created a new Project by using

```
tns create my-first-app --template tns-template-hello-world-ng
```

Then I added iOS and Android Platform by using following command

```
tns platform add ios
tns platform add android
```

When executing

```
tns run android
```

everything works fine. The Emulator is starting and the app opens up.

However, when running

```
tns run ios
```

I get following error:

```
Searching for Devices...
spawn EACCES
```

I already tried to change permissions on app directory

```
sudo chmod -R a+rwx /[AppFolder]
```

executing

```
sudo tns run ios
```

didn't solve the problem

**EDIT 2017-10-5**
Responding to Nikolai Tsonevs answer:

executing the following **didn't** resolve the problem:

```
tns platform remove ios
npm cache clean --force
tns platform add ios
tns run ios
```

my node version is: v8.4.0
my npm version is: 5.4.2

I also executed the following to share the output with you (Assuming, that Nikolai meant ios instead of android):

```
tns platform remove ios
tns platform add ios --log trace > out.txt
```

Here's the output:

```
Loading extensions.
execFile: /usr/local/share/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb "help"
Exec uname -a 
 stdout: Darwin *** 17.0.0 Darwin Kernel Version 17.0.0: Thu Aug 24 21:48:19 PDT 2017; root:xnu-4570.1.46~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
 
 stderr: 
Exec npm -v 
 stdout: 5.4.2
 
 stderr: 
spawn: java "-version"
Exec node-gyp -v 
 stdout:  
 stderr: /bin/sh: node-gyp: command not found

Error while executing node-gyp -v: Command failed: node-gyp -v
/bin/sh: node-gyp: command not found

Exec xcodebuild -version 
 stdout: Xcode 9.0
Build version 9A235
 
 stderr: 
Exec gem which xcodeproj 
 stdout:  
 stderr: ERROR:  Can't find ruby library file or shared library xcodeproj

Error while executing gem which xcodeproj: Command failed: gem which xcodeproj
ERROR:  Can't find ruby library file or shared library xcodeproj

Exec pod --version 
 stdout:  
 stderr: /bin/sh: /usr/local/bin/pod: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Error while executing pod --version: Command failed: pod --version
/bin/sh: /usr/local/bin/pod: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Exec '/usr/local/share/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb' version 
 stdout: Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.39
Revision 3db08f2c6889-android
Installed as /usr/local/share/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb
 
 stderr: 
spawn: /usr/local/share/android-sdk/emulator/emulator "-help"
Result when throw error is false:
{ stdout: 'Android Emulator usage: emulator [options] [-qemu args]\n  options:\n    -list-avds                     list available AVDs\n    -sysdir <dir>                  search for system disk images in <dir>\n    -system <file>                 read initial system image from <file>\n    -vendor <file>                 read initial vendor image from <file>\n    -writable-system               make system & vendor image writable after \'adb remount\'\n    -datadir <dir>                 write user data into <dir>\n    -kernel <file>                 use specific emulated kernel\n    -ramdisk <file>                ramdisk image (default <system>/ramdisk.img\n    -image <file>                  obsolete, use -system <file> instead\n    -initdata <file>               same as \'-init-data <file>\'\n    -data <file>                   data image (default <datadir>/userdata-qemu.img\n    -logcat-output <file>          output file of logcat(default none)\n    -partition-size <size>         system/data partition size in MBs\n    -cache <file>                  cache partition image (default is temporary file)\n    -cache-size <size>             cache partition size in MBs\n    -no-cache                      disable the cache partition\n    -nocache                       same as -no-cache\n    -sdcard <file>                 SD card image (default <datadir>/sdcard.img\n    -snapstorage <file>            file that contains all state snapshots (default <datadir>/snapshots.img)\n    -no-snapstorage                do not mount a snapshot storage file (this disables all snapshot functionality)\n    -snapshot <name>               name of snapshot within storage file for auto-start and auto-save (default \'default-boot\')\n    -no-snapshot                   perform a full boot and do not auto-save, but qemu vmload and vmsave operate on snapstorage\n    -no-snapshot-save              do not auto-save to snapshot on exit: abandon changed state\n    -no-snapshot-load              do not auto-start from snapshot: perform a full boot\n    -snapshot-list                 show a list of available snapshots\n    -no-snapshot-update-time       do not do try to correct snapshot time on restore\n    -wipe-data                     reset the user data image (copy it from initdata)\n    -avd <name>                    use a specific android virtual device\n    -skindir <dir>                 search skins in <dir> (default <system>/skins)\n    -skin <name>                   select a given skin\n    -no-skin                       deprecated: create an AVD with no skin instead\n    -noskin                        same as -no-skin\n    -memory <size>                 physical RAM size in MBs\n    -cores <number>                Set number of CPU cores to emulator\n    -accel <mode>                  Configure emulation acceleration\n    -no-accel                      Same as \'-accel off\'\n    -ranchu                        Use new emulator backend instead of the classic one\n    -engine <engine>               Select engine. auto|classic|qemu2\n    -netspeed <speed>              maximum network download/upload speeds\n    -netdelay <delay>              network latency emulation\n    -netfast                       disable network shaping\n    -code-profile <name>           enable code profiling\n    -show-kernel                   display kernel messages\n    -shell                         enable root shell on current terminal\n    -no-jni                        disable JNI checks in the Dalvik runtime\n    -nojni                         same as -no-jni\n    -logcat <tags>                 enable logcat output with given tags\n    -no-audio                      disable audio support\n    -noaudio                       same as -no-audio\n    -audio <backend>               use specific audio backend\n    -radio <device>                redirect radio modem interface to character device\n    -port <port>                   TCP port that will be used for the console\n    -ports <consoleport>,<adbport> TCP ports used for the console and adb bridge\n    -onion <image>                 use overlay PNG image over screen\n    -onion-alpha <%age>            specify onion-skin translucency\n    -onion-rotation 0|1|2|3        specify onion-skin rotation\n    -dpi-device <dpi>              specify device\'s resolution in dpi (default 165)\n    -scale <scale>                 scale emulator window (deprecated)\n    -http-proxy <proxy>            make TCP connections through a HTTP/HTTPS proxy\n    -timezone <timezone>           use this timezone instead of the host\'s default\n    -dns-server <servers>          use this DNS server(s) in the emulated system\n    -cpu-delay <cpudelay>          throttle CPU emulation\n    -no-boot-anim                  disable animation for faster boot\n    -no-window                     disable graphical window display\n    -version                       display emulator version number\n    -report-console <socket>       report console port to remote socket\n    -gps <device>                  redirect NMEA GPS to character device\n    -shell-serial <device>         specific character device for root shell\n    -tcpdump <file>                capture network packets to file\n    -bootchart <timeout>           enable bootcharting\n    -charmap <file>                use specific key character map\n    -studio-params <file>          used by Android Studio to provide parameters\n    -prop <name>=<value>           set system property on boot\n    -shared-net-id <number>        join the shared network, using IP address 10.1.2.<number>\n    -nand-limits <nlimits>         enforce NAND/Flash read/write thresholds\n    -gpu <mode>                    set hardware OpenGLES emulation mode\n    -camera-back <mode>            set emulation mode for a camera facing back\n    -camera-front <mode>           set emulation mode for a camera facing front\n    -webcam-list                   lists web cameras available for emulation\n    -screen <mode>                 set emulated screen mode\n    -force-32bit                   always use 32-bit emulator\n    -selinux <disabled|permissive> Set SELinux to either disabled or permissive mode\n    -unix-pipe <path>              Add <path> to the list of allowed Unix pipes\n    -fixed-scale                   Use fixed 1:1 scale for the initial emulator window.\n    -wait-for-debugger             Pause on launch and wait for a debugger process to attach before resuming\n    -skip-adb-auth                 Skip adb authentication dialogue\n    -metrics-to-console            Enable usage metrics and print the messages to stdout\n    -metrics-to-file <file>        Enable usage metrics and write the messages into specified file\n\n     -qemu args...                 pass arguments to qemu\n     -qemu -h                      display qemu help\n\n     -verbose                      same as \'-debug-init\'\n     -debug <tags>                 enable/disable debug messages\n     -debug-<tag>                  enable specific debug messages\n     -debug-no-<tag>               disable specific debug messages\n\n     -help                         print this help\n     -help-<option>                print option-specific help\n\n     -help-disk-images             about disk images\n     -help-debug-tags              debug tags for -debug <tags>\n     -help-char-devices            character <device> specification\n     -help-environment             environment variables\n     -help-virtual-device          virtual device management\n     -help-sdk-images              about disk images when using the SDK\n     -help-build-images            about disk images when building Android\n     -help-all                     prints all help content\n\n',
  stderr: '',
  exitCode: 0 }
The result of checking is Android Emulator installed is:
- stdout: Android Emulator usage: emulator [options] [-qemu args]
  options:
    -list-avds                     list available AVDs
    -sysdir <dir>                  search for system disk images in <dir>
    -system <file>                 read initial system image from <file>
    -vendor <file>                 read initial vendor image from <file>
    -writable-system               make system & vendor image writable after 'adb remount'
    -datadir <dir>                 write user data into <dir>
    -kernel <file>                 use specific emulated kernel
    -ramdisk <file>                ramdisk image (default <system>/ramdisk.img
    -image <file>                  obsolete, use -system <file> instead
    -initdata <file>               same as '-init-data <file>'
    -data <file>                   data image (default <datadir>/userdata-qemu.img
    -logcat-output <file>          output file of logcat(default none)
    -partition-size <size>         system/data partition size in MBs
    -cache <file>                  cache partition image (default is temporary file)
    -cache-size <size>             cache partition size in MBs
    -no-cache                      disable the cache partition
    -nocache                       same as -no-cache
    -sdcard <file>                 SD card image (default <datadir>/sdcard.img
    -snapstorage <file>            file that contains all state snapshots (default <datadir>/snapshots.img)
    -no-snapstorage                do not mount a snapshot storage file (this disables all snapshot functionality)
    -snapshot <name>               name of snapshot within storage file for auto-start and auto-save (default 'default-boot')
    -no-snapshot                   perform a full boot and do not auto-save, but qemu vmload and vmsave operate on snapstorage
    -no-snapshot-save              do not auto-save to snapshot on exit: abandon changed state
    -no-snapshot-load              do not auto-start from snapshot: perform a full boot
    -snapshot-list                 show a list of available snapshots
    -no-snapshot-update-time       do not do try to correct snapshot time on restore
    -wipe-data                     reset the user data image (copy it from initdata)
    -avd <name>                    use a specific android virtual device
    -skindir <dir>                 search skins in <dir> (default <system>/skins)
    -skin <name>                   select a given skin
    -no-skin                       deprecated: create an AVD with no skin instead
    -noskin                        same as -no-skin
    -memory <size>                 physical RAM size in MBs
    -cores <number>                Set number of CPU cores to emulator
    -accel <mode>                  Configure emulation acceleration
    -no-accel                      Same as '-accel off'
    -ranchu                        Use new emulator backend instead of the classic one
    -engine <engine>               Select engine. auto|classic|qemu2
    -netspeed <speed>              maximum network download/upload speeds
    -netdelay <delay>              network latency emulation
    -netfast                       disable network shaping
    -code-profile <name>           enable code profiling
    -show-kernel                   display kernel messages
    -shell                         enable root shell on current terminal
    -no-jni                        disable JNI checks in the Dalvik runtime
    -nojni                         same as -no-jni
    -logcat <tags>                 enable logcat output with given tags
    -no-audio                      disable audio support
    -noaudio                       same as -no-audio
    -audio <backend>               use specific audio backend
    -radio <device>                redirect radio modem interface to character device
    -port <port>                   TCP port that will be used for the console
    -ports <consoleport>,<adbport> TCP ports used for the console and adb bridge
    -onion <image>                 use overlay PNG image over screen
    -onion-alpha <%age>            specify onion-skin translucency
    -onion-rotation 0|1|2|3        specify onion-skin rotation
    -dpi-device <dpi>              specify device's resolution in dpi (default 165)
    -scale <scale>                 scale emulator window (deprecated)
    -http-proxy <proxy>            make TCP connections through a HTTP/HTTPS proxy
    -timezone <timezone>           use this timezone instead of the host's default
    -dns-server <servers>          use this DNS server(s) in the emulated system
    -cpu-delay <cpudelay>          throttle CPU emulation
    -no-boot-anim                  disable animation for faster boot
    -no-window                     disable graphical window display
    -version                       display emulator version number
    -report-console <socket>       report console port to remote socket
    -gps <device>                  redirect NMEA GPS to character device
    -shell-serial <device>         specific character device for root shell
    -tcpdump <file>                capture network packets to file
    -bootchart <timeout>           enable bootcharting
    -charmap <file>                use specific key character map
    -studio-params <file>          used by Android Studio to provide parameters
    -prop <name>=<value>           set system property on boot
    -shared-net-id <number>        join the shared network, using IP address 10.1.2.<number>
    -nand-limits <nlimits>         enforce NAND/Flash read/write thresholds
    -gpu <mode>                    set hardware OpenGLES emulation mode
    -camera-back <mode>            set emulation mode for a camera facing back
    -camera-front <mode>           set emulation mode for a camera facing front
    -webcam-list                   lists web cameras available for emulation
    -screen <mode>                 set emulated screen mode
    -force-32bit                   always use 32-bit emulator
    -selinux <disabled|permissive> Set SELinux to either disabled or permissive mode
    -unix-pipe <path>              Add <path> to the list of allowed Unix pipes
    -fixed-scale                   Use fixed 1:1 scale for the initial emulator window.
    -wait-for-debugger             Pause on launch and wait for a debugger process to attach before resuming
    -skip-adb-auth                 Skip adb authentication dialogue
    -metrics-to-console            Enable usage metrics and print the messages to stdout
    -metrics-to-file <file>        Enable usage metrics and write the messages into specified file

     -qemu args...                 pass arguments to qemu
     -qemu -h                      display qemu help

     -verbose                      same as '-debug-init'
     -debug <tags>                 enable/disable debug messages
     -debug-<tag>                  enable specific debug messages
     -debug-no-<tag>               disable specific debug messages

     -help                         print this help
     -help-<option>                print option-specific help

     -help-disk-images             about disk images
     -help-debug-tags              debug tags for -debug <tags>
     -help-char-devices            character <device> specification
     -help-environment             environment variables
     -help-virtual-device          virtual device management
     -help-sdk-images              about disk images when using the SDK
     -help-build-images            about disk images when building Android
     -help-all                     prints all help content


- stderr: 
Exec mono --version 
 stdout:  
 stderr: /bin/sh: mono: command not found

Error while executing mono --version: Command failed: mono --version
/bin/sh: mono: command not found

Exec git --version 
 stdout: git version 2.13.5 (Apple Git-94)
 
 stderr: 
Exec gradle -v 
 stdout:  
 stderr: /bin/sh: gradle: command not found

Error while executing gradle -v: Command failed: gradle -v
/bin/sh: gradle: command not found

Exec "/Library/Java/Home/bin/javac" -version 
 stdout:  
 stderr: javac 1.8.0_144

System information:
{ procInfo: 'nativescript/3.2.1',
  platform: 'darwin',
  os: 'Darwin *** 17.0.0 Darwin Kernel Version 17.0.0: Thu Aug 24 21:48:19 PDT 2017; root:xnu-4570.1.46~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64\n',
  shell: '/bin/bash',
  dotNetVer: null,
  procArch: 'x64',
  nodeVer: 'v8.4.0',
  npmVer: '5.4.2',
  javaVer: '1.8.0',
  nodeGypVer: null,
  xcodeVer: 'Xcode 9.0\nBuild version 9A235\n',
  xcodeprojGemLocation: null,
  itunesInstalled: true,
  cocoapodVer: null,
  adbVer: 'Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.39',
  emulatorInstalled: true,
  monoVer: null,
  gitVer: '2.13.5 (Apple Git-94)',
  gradleVer: null,
  javacVersion: '1.8.0_144' }
Looking for project in '/Users/***/Documents/NativeScript/my-first-app'
Project directory is '/Users/***/Documents/NativeScript/my-first-app'.
Exec which xcodebuild 
 stdout: /usr/bin/xcodebuild
 
 stderr: 
Exec xcodebuild -version | head -n 1 | sed -e 's/Xcode //' 
 stdout: 9.0
 
 stderr: 
Initializing analytics statuses.
Analytics statuses:  { TrackFeatureUsage: 'disabled', TrackExceptions: 'disabled' }
Creating NativeScript project for the ios platform
Path: /Users/***/Documents/NativeScript/my-first-app/platforms/ios
Package: org.nativescript.myfirstapp
Name: myfirstapp
Copying template files...
[0G  [96m◜ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◠ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◝ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◞ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◡ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◟ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◜ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◠ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◝ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◞ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◡ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◟ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◜ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◠ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◝ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0mExec npm view tns-ios  dist-tags --json 
 stdout: {
  "latest": "3.2.0",
  "next": "3.2.0-2017-9-5-2",
  "rc": "3.2.0-rc-2017-9-5-2"
}
 
 stderr: 
Using version 3.2.0. 
Installing  tns-ios
spawn: npm "install" "tns-ios@3.2.0" "--silent" "--save-exact" "--save"
[0G  [96m◞ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◡ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◟ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◜ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◠ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◝ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◞ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◡ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◟ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◜ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◠ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◝ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◞ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◡ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◟ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◜ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◠ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◝ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◞ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◡ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◟ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◜ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◠ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◝ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◞ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◡ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◟ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◜ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◠ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◝ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◞ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◡ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◟ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◜ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◠ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◝ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◞ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◡ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◟ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◜ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◠ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◝ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◞ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◡ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m+ tns-ios@3.2.0
added 1 package in 2.314s
spawn: npm "install" "tns-ios@3.2.0" "--silent" "--save-exact" "--save" "--json" "--dry-run" "--prefix" "/Users/***/Documents/NativeScript/my-first-app"
[0G  [96m◟ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◜ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◠ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◝ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◞ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◡ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◟ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◜ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◠ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◝ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◞ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◡ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◟ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◜ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◠ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◝ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◞ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◡ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◟ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0mFound shared scheme at xcschemeFilePath, renaming to match project name.
Checkpoint 0
Checkpoint 1
Checkpoint 2
[0G  [96m◜ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◠ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◝ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◞ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◡ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◟ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◜ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◠ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◝ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◞ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◡ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◟ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◜ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◠ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◝ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◞ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◡ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0m[0G  [96m◟ [90mInstalling tns-ios[0mExec npm uninstall tns-ios --save 
 stdout: removed 1 package in 0.473s
 
 stderr: 
[0G[2KProject successfully created.
```

**Edit: 2017-10-06**
In result to Nikolay's answer I did the following:

```
npm i -g node-gyp
sudo gem install xcodeproj
brew install mono
brew install gradle (was not installed as well)
brew install cocoapods
brew link -overwrite cocoapods (brew was complaining about link issues)
```

after that I removed iOS again and added it. This didn't work as well.

I executed the following to get further information:

```
tns run ios --log trace > run.txt
```

Here is the relevant output:

```
Looking for project in '/Users/***/Documents/NativeScript/my-first-app'
Project directory is '/Users/***/Documents/NativeScript/my-first-app'.
Exec which xcodebuild 
 stdout: /usr/bin/xcodebuild
 
 stderr: 
Exec xcodebuild -version | head -n 1 | sed -e 's/Xcode //' 
 stdout: 9.0
 
 stderr: 
Validate options for platform: iOS
Initializing analytics statuses.
Analytics statuses:  { TrackFeatureUsage: 'disabled', TrackExceptions: 'disabled' }
Searching for devices...
startLookingForDevices; platform is iOS
Starting to look for iOS devices.
Error while checking for devices. { Error: spawn EACCES
    at _errnoException (util.js:1041:11)
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:325:11)
    at exports.spawn (child_process.js:493:9)
    at IOSDeviceLibStdioHandler.startReadingData (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/ios-device-lib/ios-device-lib-stdio-handler.js:18:18)
    at new IOSDeviceLib (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/ios-device-lib/index.js:36:34)
    at IOSDeviceOperations.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/mobile/ios/device/ios-device-operations.js:55:34)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/mobile/ios/device/ios-device-operations.js:13:71
    at Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/mobile/ios/device/ios-device-operations.js:9:12) code: 'EACCES', errno: 'EACCES', syscall: 'spawn' }
Exec ps cax | grep launchd_sim 
 stdout:  4864   ??  R      0:00.17 launchd_sim
 
 stderr: 
Found device with identifier '9B7746B9-D04D-4C57-9158-4A5A28D5AA08'
startLookingForDevices; platform is iOS
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks the very great help of Nikolay I finally could resolve the problem.

Permissions where not properly set on the NativeScript node modules so I did the following:

```
chmod -R +x /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/
```

Answer (score 3):

Could you try cleaning npm cache with

1. `npm cache clean`
2. remove platform with `tns platform remove ios`
3. add it again with `tns platform add ios`
4. start the application with `tns run ios`

If the problem still persists, could you remove again the platform with `tns platform remove ios` and add it again
`tns platform add android --log trace > out.txt`
Then you could share the output from the out.txt file, which could help to investigate further the problem. Also, provide an info about your `node` and `npm` versions.

Edit:

Hi @Anton Due the provided log I found that there are several errors, which are thrown while adding the platform. The first one is that the `node-gyp` plugin is not found. To resolve this you have two options.

The first one is to install the plugin manually with `npm install node-gyp --g`. If this does not resolve the case I would suggest cleaning the npm cache with `npm cache clear` and downgrading to the latest LTS node version 6.11.4.

Regarding the two other errors make sure that you have installed `xcodeproj` and `cocoapods`. If not install them while following:`sudo gem install xcodeproj` `sudo gem install cocoapods`

Comment: Hi Nikolay, Thanks for your help. I installed the missing packages but again I'm stuck. See my Edit for the log / steps I've done.

Comment: Thanks for your support :)